# Adding obstacles and targets from shapefile in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I am new to NetLogo, so my apologies in advance if that question is very stupid. I would like to create an Agent-Based Model where animals move around in a complex terrain looking for water sources. Movement should be downhill, constrained by steep slopes (>25°) and targets should be lakes. I am using a real-world example from GIS data for this, and I have already managed to setup a world containing an ASCII elevation grid, a shapefile containing lines that represent slopes steeper 25degrees and a shapefile containing areas representing lakes. I have created animals (cows) and found a code line telling them to move downhill. Now, I would like to tell them

a) to avoid slopes >25° by using the slope shapefiles as obstacles and

b) to go to the lakes by using the lake shapfiles as targets

Can someone help me how to code this?
Many thanks in advance!
Here is the code I have put together so far

```
breed [ cows cow ]

extensions [ gis ]
patches-own [ elevation ]

globals [ 
  slope-dataset
  lake-dataset
elevation-dataset
]

to setup-terrain

  clear-all

  reset-ticks

set slope-dataset gis:load-dataset "FILENAME.shp" ;;extent of GIS datasets is N42.3-43.4 and W120.0-121.1

set lake-dataset gis:load-dataset "FILENAME.shp"

set elevation-dataset gis:load-dataset "FILENAME.asc"

gis:set-world-envelope gis:envelope-of slope-dataset

gis:set-world-envelope gis:envelope-of lake-dataset

gis:set-world-envelope gis:envelope-of elevation-dataset

end

to display-slopes


gis:set-drawing-color red

gis:draw slope-dataset 0.5

end


to display-lakes

gis:set-drawing-color blue

gis:draw lake-dataset 2

end


to display-elevation-in-patches

gis:apply-raster elevation-dataset elevation

let min-elevation gis:minimum-of elevation-dataset

let max-elevation gis:maximum-of elevation-dataset

ask patches

[ ; note the use of the "<= 0 or >= 0" technique to filter out

; "not a number" values, as discussed in the documentation.

if (elevation <= 0) or (elevation >= 0)

[ set pcolor scale-color black elevation min-elevation max-elevation ] ]

end


to setup-cows

set-default-shape cows "cow"

create-cows 100 [

setxy random-pxcor random-pycor

set size 1

set color white
  ]

end


to move

move-to patch-here ;; go to patch center

let p min-one-of neighbors [elevation]

if [elevation] of p < elevation [

face p

move-to p ;; makes cows move to the next lower elevation patch, if no lower 
elevetion is present, cow doesn't move
  ]

end


to go

ask cows [

move
  ]
end
```

Comment: what are you stuck on here, exactly? "can someone help me" isn't really a question...

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for being too vague in my first post. I am stuck on finding a way to have the cows indentify my input shapefiles as obstacles or targets, respectively. I have found examples where patches of a certain color (or elevation if an elevation model is used as input file) can be used as obstacles or targets but I have not managed to use shapefiles for this as well. Is this even possible?

Comment: I haven't used the GIS extension myself, but glancing through at http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/gis.html, primitives such as `gis:intersects?` and `gis:contains?` seem relevant?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Seth, I have found the solution using the gis:intersects? primitive you suggested:

```
to display-slopes
ask patches gis:intersecting slope-dataset
[ set pcolor red ]
end 

to go
ask cows
[fd 1
avoid-ostacles]
tick
end

to avoid-obstacles 
ask cows [
if [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = red 
[rt 90 fd 1]] 
end
```

This way I can color the patches in red that intersect with the shapefile containing the slope vector dataset and then ask the cows to avoid and move around red colored patches.
Thanks again!